# How can I get and send string in UTF-8 from c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, string, dll, utf-8

I have problem with this:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("Configuration.xml", FileMode.Open);
Encoding u8 = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, u8);
string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Configuration.xml is in utf-8, but str isn't, then I should send this str to my dll, dll functions won't work with noUTF-8

Answer (score 3):

If you really do need to start with a C# string, you must convert that string to UTF-8, stored in a byte array:

```
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Then pass that byte array to the DLL. Note that the byte array will not be null-terminated so if the DLL requires a null-terminator, you will need to explicitly add it.

On the other, hand, it would probably be much easier to avoid the trip from UTF-8 to UTF-16 and back to UTF-8 again. So, don't use `StreamReader` to read in a string. Read the file's contents directly into a byte array.

```
byte[] utf8 = File.ReadAllBytes("Configuration.xml");
```

Again, this will not have a null-terminator and so if it is needed, you must add it.

If you do need a null-terminator then it may be easier with a `FileStream`:

1. Create the `FileStream` in read mode.
2. Find the size of the file by reading the `Length` property.
3. Allocate a byte array of length `Stream.Length+1` bytes. The new memory will be zero-initialized so the final byte already has your null-terminator.
4. Call `Read` on the file stream to read `Stream.Length` bytes into the byte array.

Something like this:

```
byte[] ReadAsNullTerminatedByteArray(string filename)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length+1];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, fs.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I should send this str to my dll, one way. In string type, not in byte

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You need to pass it as a byte array because p/invoke marshalling does not speak UTF-8. You'll need to declare the `char*` parameter as `byte[]`.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I then act in c + +?

Comment: On the C++ side you receive a parameter of type `const char*`. If you wish you may elect also to receive the length. That removes the necessity for null-termination. But that might be inconvenient. I cannot provide you C++ code because I've no idea what you are doing on the C++ side of this interface. I am reasonably confident that I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use your method =(

Comment: What part are you struggling to understand? Try to be very precise when you make comments. "I can't use your method" gives me no real information. For a start I offered a number of different ways to tackle your problem.

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not know much English and I answer as I can. Unfortunately I can not use your method in my program, that's all I wanted to say, but thank you very much for trying to

Comment: This is the answer to the question that you asked.